# wpf ElementHost doesn't show

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having quite a bit of an issue with this `ElementHost` thing. Can someone please take a look at what I have and let me know what's going on or why this isn't showing? Everything seems to work, it's just that I can't see the `ElementHost` displayed/refresh on the screen (user control).

Test.cs.designer

```
this.TestHost.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.TestHost.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
this.TestHost.Name = "TestHost";
this.TestHost.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1139, 213);
this.TestHost.TabIndex = 1;
this.TestHost.Text = "elementHost1";
this.TestHost.Child = this.testview1;
this.TestHost.Visible = true;
```

Test.cs

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadView(item);
}

public void LoadView(Person item)
{
    TestHost.Child = this.testview1; //name given when drag/drop .. should still reference wpf TestView xaml

    try
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            // TestView is WPF xaml/View                
            TestView view = new TestView();
            view = (TestView) TestHost.Child;
            //TestViewModel is a viewmodel

            TestViewModel vm = (TestViewModel) view.DataContext;
            //load items from viewmodel             
            vm.LoadItems(item);
        }   

        TestHost.Visible = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, but, you can write instead of `TestHost.Visible = true;`, `TestHost.Visibility = Visibility.Visible`

Comment: @Dante -- I just want to display the View on my form and TestHost.Visibility = Visibility.Visible doesnt work because everything is in Test.cs.

Comment: Before all, why is it visible=false at the beginning? 
Now, after setting it to visible call the 'Refresh' method to force to render

Comment: @Luis Filipe -- if I set background to red in the designer, I do see the elementhost's background filled in red. however, it's not displaying the view that I want to see. I've tried your suggestion but to no avail. any ideas?

Comment: You have a Windows Form with an element host in it, right? Did you drag&drop your WPF user control into the windows form?

Answer (score 1):

From you code it looks like you're setting your elementhost child to a Class instead of an instance of it (which would not compile). My question is **where does TestView instance is coming from?**

```
TestHost.Child = TestView;
```

To debug, in your try/catch block change 'ex.ToString()' to show a message box; If an exception occurs you'll be aware of it.

Comment: I did drag and drop my wpf user control and it updated the child for me. I did set visible = true also and when i ran it, I do see my view but i'm not seeing my data populated inside my view although when i step through it, and hover over "vm", i see the correct data.

Comment: what does "TestView" come from? Is it a BindingList?
How are you binding it to your user control?
Consider to edit your question to include these, please

Comment: TestView is the name of the view. So, I was looking at some example and by using elementhost, my initial thought is, when "LoadItem" is executed in the viewmodel, this would automatically update the view because this "LoadItem" execute a Stored Procedure in the viewmodel to return the data. Does this make sense? As I said, when I hover over "vm.LoadItems(item);" once this is executed, vm has all the correct data. My only issue is, the elementhost which holds the WPF View "TestView", doesnt update in my usercontrol. Pretty much, it display the view without any data.

Comment: I can't fully understand how you bind your data in the 'TestView' instance to the UserControl. Do you do it by XAML? You need to tell the UserControl what data to display.

Comment: please take a look at what I've edited. Yes, I believe i do this by xaml. So how do i tell the usercontrol to display what data? can you show me an example of how to do so? I've been going in circles for a few days now and would really appreciate your help.